# MSI File for GWT incl. Database and Tomcat?

Tags: java, database, tomcat, windows-installer

I have written an application in Java\GWT, It needs a database and Tomcat.
With what program can I create an msi File? that database, Tomcat and my application will be installed?

I know InstallShield and it is very expensive.

I want my application to be someone. He just wants to run a setup and then use it (all in one setup e.g. install App, Database and Tomcat incl. conf.)?

Answer (score 2):

NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) is a great open-source tool for creating windows installers - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page As far as I know it does not support MSI but it's still a great tool if exe files are ok.

http://wixtoolset.org/ is also open source and creates MSI files but I haven't used it and don't know if it's any good.